# I want to add multiple choice option to opencart 3.0+ shipping cost

Tags: opencart, opencart-module, opencart-3

I want to add multiple choice option to `opencart` 3.0+ shipping cost,
like currently we can only select on option from shipping but I want to select multiple options like image below:

[image: Open cart shipping custom option]

Answer (score 1):

A different solution to the problem would be to add *options* for washing machine in the washing machine category so that it will be displayed only when a user purchases a washing machine. In order to do this add custom options for each washing machine product.

This can be solved by doing the following:

```
Admin > catalog > Options > add Washing machine(Baumatic...) > select type as 
checkbox > add 2 Option value Installation & Remove.
```

For each washing machine product:

```
Admin > Catalog > product > edit washing machine product > go to options Tab > 
select washing machine(option we add above) > add price for installation & remove.
```

This solution can be applid to all three categories in your provided example.

I hope this is useful to you.

Comment: cant do that because it should only come if the shipping zip within 20 miles, like the screen shot i made a shipping method for tracking shipping distance